# Spring AOP logging for HTTP request

Tags: spring, logging, aop

I am trying to log the http request in controller by aop. However, in the aspect code, if I

```
    httpServletRequest.getInputStream()
```

then the request data will not be able to retrieve in main flow.

So, I created another public method with in the controller which pass in the request string

```
    public String processRequest(String data){...}
```

and this method is a pointcut for logging the "data".

But the problem is, seems the point cut for this method is not be able to identify by Spring, there is no logging for this method. I need help on this.

Here is the define for the aop

```
     <bean id="myLogger" class="com.my.MyLogger" />

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="Log" ref="myLogger">
        <aop:around  method="log" pointcut="execution(public * com.my.controller.processRequest(..))" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring AOP by default uses AOP proxies. So your original bean is wrapped with generated proxy bean and all "outside" calls go through the proxy. Internal method calls (within the same bean) bypass proxy.

It's nicely explained here:  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies